# Correct way to use Sub query in sql

Tags: php, sql

I have certain problems in using multiple sub queries,

Is there something like this?

My current query:

```sql
SELECT A.category_one as cat1, B.category_two as cat2, C.category_three as cat3
FROM table1
(SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE user_id ='32') A
(SELECT age FROM table1 WHERE age='12') B
(SELECT gender FROM table1 WHERE user_id ='32') C
WHERE ticket_id='12'
```

So if I fetch the result with PHP I could echo the data like

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
   echo $value['cat1'] . ' ' . $value['cat2'] . ' ' . $value['cat3'] . "<br>";
}
```

Was the query correct? If not, what would be the correct way of doing it?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you getting an error when you run the query?

Comment: What do you want your query to do?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output. Your intent is incomprehensible from what you've posted.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What's in the table

Comment: The method you've chosen to get at the data looks to be the main issue, but it's difficult to provide specific solutions without more info

Answer (score 0):

need a small improvement on

```
(SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE user_id ='32') A
(SELECT gender FROM table1 WHERE user_id ='32') C
```

to

```
(SELECT name,gender FROM table1 WHERE user_id='32')A
```

since your where clause for A and C is same and make sure put 'C.category_three as cat3'
back to 'A.category_three as cat3'

Comment: The category fields aren't available from the fields selected in the subqueries.

Comment: i just suggest, it will be good if he provide all column in table

Comment: I started writting a similar answer, but gave up because of the amount of assumtions I was having to make - I think the question's wrong and it'll be a matter of a join or where statement as the best solution... hard to tell at the moment!

Comment: i also know by doing this `Join(SELECT name,gender FROM table1 WHERE user_id='32')A on Table_1.user_id = A.user_id` . but i don't know about fetching result will be same or not and question is not clearly what it say

Answer (score 0):

The SQL and question are not well formed in the following respects:

1) There are syntax errors in the SQL (e.g. missing commas between the subqueries). You should fix those first (e.g. on SQLFiddle) unless you are absolutely stuck in doing so. Since the query is pretty simple, that shouldn't be a problem

2) You haven't provided any JOIN information whatsover.  In the absence of that you'll get the cross product of the results of these queries. If they each return exactly one row, you're ok, since you'll get exactly one row of output. However, since you implied with the `for` loop that you expect multiple rows to be returned, that's probably not the case.  If you're not familiar with the concept of JOINing, you probably should learn about that before going any further.

3) As others have pointed out, you haven't provided any sample of input data and output results. That's always a good idea and given the lack of a clear English description, as is the case here, absolutely necessary.